# Scrolling vertical list UI with variable sized text items?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a specific type of scrolling list UI to implement in my web application, but I do not know what it is called and can't seem to find it in a search.  It is similar to a coverflow, but for a scrolling list of text items.  Maybe more like a thumbwheel?

Basically, it would show 5 items.  The 3rd item is in large type and is the selected item.  The 2nd and 4th items are slightly smaller font and 1st and 5th items are smaller than that.

Clicking on any item in the list would scroll it into the 3rd (selected) position.

Any help would be appreciated.

> #### Item 1
>
> ### Item 2
>
> ## Item 3 (selected)
>
> ### Item 4
>
> #### Item 5

Comment: You're thinking of the native iOS select element. There's no native way of replicating that on the web. You'll just have to search for a plugin that simulates your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you.  Based on that I found this that is close to what I was thinking:
http://maklesoft.github.io/spin-select/spin-select/demo.html